Passing functions to casesOn which do not depend on a pattern match
In Chapter 8 of Theorem Proving with Lean4, there's the following example of a tail function for dependent lists:
inductive Vector (α : Type u) : Nat → Type u
  | nil  : Vector α 0
  | cons : α → {n : Nat} → Vector α n → Vector α (n+1)

def tailAux (v : Vector α m) : m = n + 1 → Vector α n :=
  Vector.casesOn (motive := fun x _ => x = n + 1 → Vector α n) v
    (fun h : 0 = n + 1 => Nat.noConfusion h)
    (fun (a : α) (m : Nat) (as : Vector α m) =>
     fun (h : m + 1 = n + 1) =>
       Nat.noConfusion h (fun h1 : m = n => h1 ▸ as))

def tail (v : Vector α (n+1)) : Vector α n :=
  tailAux v rfl

My question is, why is the author passing (fun h : 0 = n + 1 => Nat.noConfusion h) to Vector.casesOn, even though it does not at all seem to be matching on Vector.nil? Why is this not causing an error?

Note that Vector.casesOn is a function term. This is the output of #check Vector.casesOn:
Vector.casesOn.{u_1, u} {α : Type u} {motive : (a : Nat) → Vector α a → Sort u_1} :
  {a : Nat} →
    (t : Vector α a) →
      motive 0 Vector.nil → ((a : α) → {n : Nat} → (a_1 : Vector α n) → motive (n + 1) (Vector.cons a a_1)) → motive a t

Note that the second mandatory argument has type motive 0 Vector.nil. This is exactly what (fun h : 0 = n + 1 => Nat.noConfusion h) fills in. Since this is a mandatory argument, Lean will not attempt to fill it in for you.
Vector.casesOn (among others) is used in the elaboration of pattern matching. The definition you have is "morally equivalent" to:
def tailAux' (v : Vector α m) (h : m = n + 1) : Vector α n :=
  match m, v, h with
  | _, .cons _ v, rfl => v  

But, in this case, the Lean elaborator fills in many details for you, including the fact that the case v matches Vector.nil is impossible and therefore not necessary.

Thanks for the help!
